# cocos2d/cocos2d-x stopping particle system gracefully

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, particle-system

Is there a way to stop a particle system gracefully -- ie. I call stop, and the particles dissipate naturally, no new particles are generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `ParticleSystemQuad`. So, to stop particles emitting, I set

```
particle->stopSystem();
particle->setAutoRemoveOnFinish(true);
```

It stops the particle emission and then, after disappearing last particle, auto removes particle system.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can also set Visible false Or Remove from parant

ParticleSystemQuad *m_emitter=ParticleSystemQuad::create(ch);
m_emitter->setVisible(true);
this->addChild(m_emitter,50);
m_emitter->setPosition(100,100);





m_emitter->setVisible(false);

         Or

m_emitter->runAction(Sequence::create(DelayTime::create(3.0),RemoveSelf::create(), NULL));
```